# When filtering i get error Uncaught TypeError: canvas is null with Chart.js and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: canvas is null when i filter the different type of data, sometimes it works and then i get this error after i filtered like 2-3 times. I tried to load the data slower but it does not work. And i destroy the Chart everytime before i load a new one in. This is my FixtureChart.vue file

```
<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
export default {
  props: {
    // Declare the id prop
    filterData: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    filterType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null,
      overallData: null,
      labelName: null,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    async filterData() {
      await this.beforeDestroy();
      await this.renderChart();
    },
    async filterType() {
      await this.beforeDestroy();
      await this.renderChart();
    },
  },

  async mounted() {
    await this.renderChart();
  },
  methods: {
    async renderChart() {
      const ctx = this.$refs.fixtureChart;

      let chartData;
      let labelsData;
      switch (this.filterType) {
        case null:
        case "goals_scored":
          let goalsAndRoundData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              goals_scored: item.goals_scored,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = goalsAndRoundData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.goals_scored);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Mål"
          break;

        case "assists":
          let assistData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              assists: item.assists,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = assistData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.assists);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Assister"
          break;

        case "expected_goals":
          let expected_goalsData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              expected_goals: item.expected_goals,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = expected_goalsData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.expected_goals);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Förväntade mål"
          break;

        case "expected_assists":
          let expected_assistsData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              expected_assists: item.expected_assists,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = expected_assistsData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.expected_assists);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Förväntade assister"
          break;

        case "expected_goal_involvements":
          let expected_goal_involvementsData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              expected_goal_involvements: item.expected_goal_involvements,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = expected_goal_involvementsData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.expected_goal_involvements);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Förväntade inbladningar i mål"
          break;

        case "clean_sheets":
          let clean_sheetsData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              clean_sheets: item.clean_sheets,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = clean_sheetsData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.clean_sheets);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Hållna nollor"
          break;

        case "goals_conceded":
          let goals_concededData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              goals_conceded: item.goals_conceded,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = goals_concededData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.goals_conceded);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Insläppta mål"
          break;

        case "expected_goals_conceded":
          let expected_goals_concededData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              expected_goals_conceded: item.expected_goals_conceded,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = expected_goals_concededData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.expected_goals_conceded);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Förväntade insläppta mål"
          break;

        case "total_points":
          let total_pointsData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              total_points: item.total_points,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = total_pointsData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.total_points);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Poäng"
          break;

        case "bonus":
          let bonusData = this.filterData.map(item => {
            return {
              bonus: item.bonus,
              round: item.round
            };
          });
          this.overallData = bonusData;
          chartData = this.overallData.map(item => item.bonus);
          labelsData = this.overallData.map(item => `GW ${item.round}`);
          this.labelName = "Bonuspoäng"
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }

      this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: labelsData,
          datasets: [{
            label: this.labelName,
            data: chartData,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#320b4c',
            backgroundColor: '#320b4c'
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: false,
              reverse: false
            }
          },
          plugins: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Rankning över säsongen"
            }
          }
        },
      });
    },
    async beforeDestroy() {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.destroy();
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <canvas ref="fixtureChart"></canvas>
</template>
```

This is my FixtureHistory.vue file:

```
<script>
import FixtureChart from '../../components/PremPlayersStats/FixtureChart.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    FixtureChart,
  },
  props: {
    history: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      filterType: null,
      filterCategories: [
        { value: null, text: 'Sortera' },
        { value: 'goals_scored', text: 'Gjorda mål' },
        { value: 'assists', text: 'Assist' },
        { value: 'expected_goals', text: 'Förväntade mål' },
        { value: 'expected_assists', text: 'Förväntade assister' },
        { value: 'expected_goal_involvements', text: 'Förväntade inbladningar i mål' },
        { value: 'clean_sheets', text: 'Hållna nollor' },
        { value: 'goals_conceded', text: 'Insläppta mål' },
        { value: 'expected_goals_conceded', text: 'Förväntade insläppta mål' },
        { value: 'total_points', text: 'Poäng' },
        { value: 'bonus', text: 'Bonuspoäng' },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {},
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="table-title rounded-top">
    <h5>Chart</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column pt-3 px-3 white-container rounded-bottom">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
      <h4>Statistik</h4>
      <select v-model="filterType" class="form-select filter_type w-25">
        <option v-for="category in filterCategories" :value="category.value">
          {{ category.text }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <FixtureChart :filterData="history" :filterType="filterType" v-if="history" />
    <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3" v-else>
      <b-spinner class="color-text-custom" label="Loading..."></b-spinner>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example where the problem can be seen

Comment: Your use scenario seems very suitable to using the `chart.update` approach, see [Updating charts docs section](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-charts). That being said, your actual code needs debugging. I'd start by logging the values `this.$refs.fixtureChart` each time the `renderChart` method is called. Or you could let us debug it, if you provided a running simplified version of your code in a stackblitz or codesandbox.